# Send "raw" payload to Axios

Tags: javascript, axios

How can I send a raw payload/request body to Axios?

The endpoint I'm trying to call expects the request body to just be a string which it'll scoop up and use.

If I try to just pass a string to `axios.post()` for the `requestBody`, it'll convert it to an object with no value (`{ "this+is+my+message": "" }`) and ends up getting parsed like this `"this+is+my+message="`.

I checked the documentation, but couldn't find any option that seemed to work. `transformRequest` seemed to be the most obvious, but it sent in the string and I sent out the string (literally `d => d`), but it still seemed to convert it to a valueless JSON object.

Answer (score 20):

It turns out, if I set the `Content-Type` header to `text/plain`, it won't convert it to JSON or form data and will send it as I want.

```
axios.post('/my-url', 'my message text', {
  headers: { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' }
});
```

Answer (score 4):

As I dropped here having a similar problem, I'd like to supply an additional answer. I am loading an image file (from a `<input type="file">` element) and sending it to the server using axios - but as raw body as opposed to wrapping it in a `multipart/form-data` request.

It seems that in the case of raw data, axios works best if the data is supplied in an `ArrayBuffer`. This can be achieved e.g. using the following code fragment (ES6):

```
  const myFile = getMyFileFromSomewhere()
  const reader = new FileReader()
  reader.onload = () => {
    const result = reader.result
    const headers = {
      'Content-Type': file.type,
      'Content-Disposition': 'attachment; filename="' + file.name + '"'
    }
    axios.post('/upload', result, { headers: headers })
  }
  reader.readAsArrayBuffer(myFile)
```

(using the `Content-Type` header in this way is slightly non-standard but in my case only used as means of transporting the original file name)

See:

https://github.com/axios/axios#request-config - description of `data`
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsArrayBuffer